# Run JS Function After JQuery-Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a WebForm that, once validated, writes to a database via a SQL query. 
I can get the validation to work independently. 
I can get the data to write independently (when I add an onclick event to the button). 
But I cannot get them to work in succession of each other. 
How do I invoke a javascript function after a successful jQuery Validation? Code can be seen below.

**activitylog.html**

```
<form action="javascript:;" id="form_rptActivityLog">
    <input id="txtShiftDate" type="text" class="form-control date-picker" name="txtShiftDate"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" title="Save" class="btn blue-hoki" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function saveData() { // ... SQL DATA WRITE HERE ... // }
</script>
```

**validation.js**

```
var ValidationScripting = function() {


// ACTIVITY LOG ICON VALIDATION
var rptActivityLogValidation = function() {
    // for more info visit the official plugin documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

    var form = $('#form_rptActivityLog');
    var error = $('.alert-danger', form);
    var success = $('.alert-success', form);

    form.validate({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "",  // validate all fields including form hidden input
        rules: {
            txtShiftDate: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit              
            success.hide();
            error.show();
            Metronic.scrollTo(error, -200);
        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
            var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
            icon.removeClass('fa-check').addClass("fa-warning");  
            icon.attr("data-original-title", error.text()).tooltip({'container': 'body'});
        },

        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-success").addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group   
        },

        unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight

        },

        success: function (label, element) {
            var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
            //$(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // set success class to the control group
            //icon.removeClass("fa-warning").addClass("fa-check");
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')          // remove check mark for success
            icon.removeClass("fa-warning")
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            success.show();
            error.hide();
            form.submit(); // submit the form
        }
    });


}


return {

    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {

        console.log('Activity Log Validation');
        rptActivityLogValidation();
    }

};

}();
```

The error I get is: 
*JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'submit'*

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling the submitHandler method?

Comment: Just a question, you are calling `form.validate` then why are you calling `form[0].submit`. Shouldn't it be `form.submit`

Comment: @Rajesh `form.submit()` would fire any submit event bound using jQuery, not `form[0].submit()`

Comment: But then shouldn't `form` be an array to use `form[0].submit`? The error clearly says that form[0] (object) doesn't have a submit event

Comment: Why are you putting the `.validate()` method inside of a function?  The `.validate()` method is just used for initializing the Validate plugin on your form and only needs to be called once within the DOM ready event handler.  And like everyone else said, you just need `form.submit()`... however, if there is nothing else inside of your `submitHandler` option, you can remove it entirely, as your code is nearly identical to the default.

Comment: Probably too much info, but I updated my entire validation.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function that you want to run *after* validation but *before* the form submit would go **inside** of your `submitHandler`; it's no different than your `success.show()`, etc.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    // form is valid and ready to submit
    // do stuff here
    success.show();
    error.hide();
    form.submit(); // submit the form
}
```

Comment: How would I call `function saveData()` from in this code block?

Comment: @rak11, have you tried `saveData()`?   The same as you would call it with any JavaScript code.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for pointing out the obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rptActivityLogValidation = function() {
    var form = $('#form_rptActivityLog')[0];

    form.validate({ 
        // .... VALIDATE FIELDS HERE ..... //

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit(); // submit the form
        }
     });
}
```

You could try this -- make the `form` var the specific form `[0]`.
Since you pass that into the submitHandler you don't need `[0]` inside it. This will make sure you're actually tageting the form.

Although we need to see how you call submitHandler. Are you actually passing the form into it?

Comment: He is not calling the `submitHandler`.  The `submitHandler` is an option of the plugin's `.validate()` method.  It's a callback that is fired when the form is valid and the submit button is clicked.